# Programmatically access most frequently used apps in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, mru

The Windows 8.1 start menu provides a list of apps that can be sorted by most used (Windows Button > Down arrow > Apps: by most used). Is there a way to programmatically get a list of these apps *in this order* in C#? If not in this order, at least a list of the most used and/or moderately used apps as displayed in the Windows 8.1 start menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is probably yes, you can, though it's not recommended (nor easy).

Raymond Chen described this pretty clearly in his blog post, ["Why is there no programmatic access to the Start menu pin list?"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030903-00/?p=42673). It talks about a different issue on Windows XP, but I think the moral of the story applies here as well, that this information is too easily abused and thus no public API is available. Stackoverflow also has a question that addresses the MFU list directly (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739839/how-can-one-manipulate-the-start-menus-recently-used-programs-list-programmat)), and the answers are that you just shouldn't do it.

The thing is, the MFU list you see is stored in the UserAssist section of the registry, and its values are encrypted (used to be ROT13, but I have no idea for 8.1). Didier Stevens wrote a GUI that decrypts the values (see [blog post](http://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/userassist/)), but it has not been updated since 8.1 came out. For what its worth the author has included the source code but it's for an older version. You can probably expand on his code to make it support 8.1 if you can do cryptanalysis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like it's ROT13 in Windows 8.1 as well, and Stevens' app decrypts all of the registry entries. I managed to decrypt a long from the binary data of the entries and it seems to keep track of the length of time the process is active, but comparing these long values to each other for the MFU programs don't seem to match up with the sort order in the start screen of Windows 8.1. All in all, it seems like it would be a lost cause in the end and just too much trouble to be worth it.