# Programmatically list common use applications

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, winapi

Does anyone know how to programmatically(C#) list common use applications?

For example,
[Show Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bMPf.png)

I am curious about how to implement it?

Comment: Not officially, one highly undocumented approach is in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500992/programmatically-access-most-frequently-used-apps-in-windows-8-1), an alternative may be to aggregate file extensions in Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent and fetch the associated executable name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would go for the registry - I guess. For example `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\`or `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.